# Using the COUNT with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the number of different sheep, and I want it in one table.

Like this;

```
Ewes | Rams | Lambs
 8   |   5  |  12
```

The query I try is this, but it doesn't work;

```
SELECT COUNT(e.EweID) AS 'Ewe', COUNT(r.RamID) AS 'Ram', COUNT(l.LambID) AS 'Lamb' 
FROM Sheep s 
    INNER JOIN Ewe e ON s.SheepID = e.EweID 
    INNER JOIN Ram r ON s.SheepID = r.RamID 
    INNER JOIN Lamb l ON s.SheepID = l.LambID 
WHERE s.FarmerID = '123'
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, this is my database ERD;

[image: s]

Comment: Could you help us out and let us know what exactly isn't working correctly?

Comment: I'd go with LEFT JOIN's here.

Comment: Try LEFT OUTER JOINs.

Comment: Sorry, the output is 0 for each one, and I know it should be; Ewe = 3, Lamb = 5, and Ram = 1

Comment: Don't use inner join if you want to count tabel data in each of those tables. You will get the same count of rows in every table because you create a hard connection between every table in inner join.

Comment: Wow, noob me. Thought I did try it with LEFT OUTER. I guess with the LEFT only. I noticed that LEFT only also work, I think I tried that yesterday but with the farmerID in the joins

Comment: LEFT JOIN is exactly the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. (The outer keyword is optional.)

Comment: @jarlh Will remember that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a `FROM` here at all:

```
select
  (select count(*) from Ram where Famerid = 123) as RamCount,
  (select count(*) from Ewe where Famerid = 123) as Count,
  (select count(*) from Lamb where Famerid = 123) as LambCount
```

(There is no relationship between the rows you are counting, do don't try and create one. Instead count each separately, wrapping it all in an outer select keeps everything in a single result row.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that you don't need an INNER JOIN but an OUTER JOIN ...

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN e.EweID IN NOT NULL THEN e.EweID ELSE 0 END) AS 'Ewe', COUNT(r.RamID) AS 'Ram', COUNT(l.LambID) AS 'Lamb' 
FROM Sheep s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Ewe e ON s.SheepID = e.EweID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Ram r ON s.SheepID = r.RamID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Lamb l ON s.SheepID = l.LambID 
WHERE s.FarmerID = '123'
```

Take a look even at the case statement that I've added inside the first count(Ewe), to see a way to handle nulls in the count .

> The Left Outer Join logical operator returns each row that satisfies
>   the join of the first (top) input with the second (bottom) input. It
>   also returns any rows from the first input that had no matching rows
>   in the second input. The nonmatching rows in the second input are
>   returned as null values. If no join predicate exists in the Argument
>   column, each row is a matching row.

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated sub-selects to do the counting:

```
SELECT (select COUNT(*) from Ewe e where s.SheepID = e.EweID) AS 'Ewe',
       (select COUNT(*) from Ram r where s.SheepID = r.RamID) AS 'Ram',
       (select COUNT(*) from Lamb l where s.SheepID = l.LambID) AS 'Lamb'
FROM Sheep s 

WHERE s.FarmerID = '123'
```

And you can also simply remove the `WHERE` clause to get all farms' counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Count1 INT;

SELECT  @Count1 = COUNT(*)
FROM    dbo.Ewe;

DECLARE @Count2 INT;

SELECT  @Count2 = COUNT(*)
FROM    dbo.Ram;

DECLARE @Count3 INT;

SELECT  @Count3 = COUNT(*)
FROM    dbo.Lamb;

SELECT  @Count1 AS 'Ewe' ,
        @Count2 AS 'Ram' , 
        @Count3 AS 'Lamb'
```